# Django, AJAX and Queryset with Foreignkey issue

Tags: ajax, django, orm, django-queryset

I try stored some data using AJAX, but I have problem with ForeignKey attribute. 
How should be look a valid queryset?

Ajax.js:

```
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/post/',
        data: {
            post: $('#post').val(),
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function(response) {
                alert('Post!');
            },
        },
    });
```

Ajax.js and urls are valid. They work good. 
It's issue with views.py and ORM QuerySet. 
Django show me:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique` is reserved with Django. This line is causing you trouble

```
unique = Board.objects.get(title=board)
```

You should change it to some other variable name something not reserved.

```
unique_board = Board.objects.get(title=board)
```

EDIT: Check manually that object matching query exists. There should be a line in the traceback that Board matching query does not exists. Check value of board that you are passing to `Board.objects.get` method and see that a row exist in the db matching to that value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still I got issue :\

Comment: I try solve this problem since 4 hours. I checked all manually.

Comment: do you see anything like `Board matching query does not exists` in your console? @WaterInTheButtle

Comment: If I try:  obj, created = Card.objects.get_or_create(Board,board=unique_board, title_card=title_card, description_card=description_card) I have a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: This line should be `Card.objects.get_or_create(board=unique_board, title_card=title_card, description_card=description_card)`.

Comment: I have: board.models.DoesNotExist: Board matching query does not exist.

Comment: There is the problem. The query you are trying does not exists in the database. In other ways the row you are trying to get from your Card table does not exists. If you check in your database you will see.

Comment: How I should repair it?

Comment: There is nothing to repair your code is fine. The problem is the data you are trying to get from your database does not exist in the database. I suggest create a Card object save it then use that value Card objects title. It would definitely work

Comment: But I use CREATE_or_get method. ORM should create new card.

Comment: Card is not the main source of problem. Change this line `unique_board = Board.objects.get(title=board)` to `unique_board = Board.objects.get_or_create(title=board, description='something', category='something')` This line was causing you the trouble. You are using only get here not get_or_create

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I have problem:     self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @WaterInTheButtle  ask another question for this. I would be happy to help you there